# Google Apps Script/URLFetchApp and using returned data

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, urlfetch

I am very new to this, so please bear with me-- I have currently have an operational google apps script on the backend of a google sheet that is generated from Google Form answers. I am essentially setting up a ticket form in google forms that will trigger the data in the corresponding sheet to be sent via api call to our ticketing system. It works great, but I am trying to optimize it currently. The goal is to take the json response I get using:

`Logger.log(response.getContentText());`

which provides me the following info:

`Aug 9, 2020, 11:44:40 AM Info    {"_url":"https://testticketingsystem.com/REST/2.0/ticket/123456","type":"ticket","id":"123456"}`

and send another API call to send data to that new ticket.

Here's a code snippet:

```
var payload = { 
    "Subject":  String(su),
    "Content":  String(as),
    "Requestor": String(em),
    "Queue": String(qu),
    "CustomFields": {"CustomField1": String(vn), "CustomField2": String(vb), "CustomField3": 
     String(vg), "CustomField4": String(av), "CustomField5": String(ov), "CustomField6": 
     String(sd)}
     }

var options = {
      'method': 'post',
      "contentType" : "application/json",
      'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
       }

var url = "https://testticketingsystem.com/REST/2.0/ticket?token=****************";

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error.toString());
  }
  }
```

After the ticket is created, how do I script the use of that ID number as a variable into my next api call?

Thank you!

Comment: can you do : `Logger.log(typeof response.getContentText())` to make sure that the response is a json file? Also try `response.getContentText().id`. The latter might give you want you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UrlFetchApp.fetch` returns a [`HTTPResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response), and if you expect JSON then you should be able to just use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to create an object from the text. (The `JSON` object is a standard JavaScript global object like `Math`; it is not Google Apps Script specific.)

If all goes well, you should just be able to use

```js
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var id = data.id;
```

and then use that `id` for your next `fetch()`.

#### Notes

If your literal response is indeed

```
Aug 9, 2020, 11:44:40 AM Info    {"_url":"https://testticketingsystem.com/REST/2.0/ticket/123456","type":"ticket","id":"123456"}
```

you will run into trouble as everything until the `{` is invalid JSON (use a [linter](https://jsonlint.com/) if you need to check yourself).  But I'm assuming that was added by the console when you logged JSON, and not in the actual response itself.

`JSON.parse()` throws an error with invalid JSON, so you can use `try/catch` if needed.

You can also check the headers before you try to `JSON.parse()`.

Here's an example that checks and handles issues, should they arise.

```js
var type = response.getHeaders()["Content-Type"];
var text = response.getContentText();
if (type === "application/json") {
  try {
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
  } catch (error) {
    return Logger.log("Invalid JSON: " + response.getContentText(text));
  }
} else {
  return Logger.log("expected JSON, but got response of type: " + type);
}
// if we get to this line, data is an object we can use
```

Comment: Thank you so much-- I knew that JSON.parse was next, but I didn't understand how to use it to store a variable. I very new to apps script, API calls and JavaScript, so I really appreciate this!