# How to find out poll id of the poll created by telegram bot?

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram bot with Google Script.

My problem is that I don't know how to get an id of created poll when I send a poll with my bot

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  if (contents.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
    handleMessage(contents.message);
  } else if (contents.hasOwnProperty('poll_answer')) {
    handlePoll(contents.poll_answer)
  }
}

function sendPoll(chatId, options) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendPoll",
      chat_id: String(chatId),
      question: "Some question:",
      options: options,
      is_anonymous: false,
      allows_multiple_answers: true,
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyboard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
  
  // How do I know here the id of the poll that was created?
}
```

I get poll_id in poll_answer but how can I find out which poll does it refer to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps Script/URLFetchApp and using returned data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328704/google-apps-script-urlfetchapp-and-using-returned-data)

Comment: @Kos yes, thank you!